# Can't get my header to display on my UIcollectionView page in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a profile page similar to that of instagram but can't get my header (UserProfileHeader.swift) to display on my UICollectionView (UserProfileVC.swift) page.

I tried to debug the code by adding print statements in each block of code as shown in the additional attached snapshot below, the only ones that prints into the console when I go to the profile page on the simulator are the ones in the numberOfSections and numberOfItemsInSection functions, I don't know if that is supposed to happen or the other functions are not being accessed. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
private let headerIdentifier = "UserProfileHeader"

class UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // MARK: Properties

    let db = Firestore.firestore() // Connects firestore

    let customGrayColor = UIColor(red: 247/255, green: 247/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let settings = db.settings
        settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
        db.settings = settings

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.collectionView!.register(UserProfileHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)


        // Background color
        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = customGrayColor

        fetchCurrentUserData()
    }


    // MARK: UICollectionView

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        print("numberOfSections works -------------------->")
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        print("numberOfItemsInSection -------------------->")
        return 0
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        print("referenceSizeForHeaderInSection -------------------->")

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        // Declare header
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UserProfileHeader
        print("dequeueReusableSupplementaryView -------------------->")

        // Return header
        return header
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell
        print("dequeueReusableCell -------------------->")
        return cell
        }
}
```

UserProfileHeader.swift script

```
import UIKit

class UserProfileHeader: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = .red

        print("UserProfileHeader -------------------->")


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Console

```
    nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7faa496143b0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-03-15 09:59:29.118574-0500 HobbiStyle[35259:1722282] [BoringSSL] 
    nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7faa496143b0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-03-15 09:59:29.119123-0500 HobbiStyle[35259:1722282] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-03-15 09:59:29.119274-0500 HobbiStyle[35259:1722282] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
numberOfSections works -------------------->
numberOfItemsInSection -------------------->
```

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense.  How do you go from "Can't get my header to display on my UIcollectionView" to subclassing UICollectionViewCell?  Why don't you just create a header or a footer view with UIView if you need one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, everything is fine with both scripts, the problem was in my tab bar controller, I declared the profileVC as UICollectionViewLayout instead of UICollectionViewFlowLayout. Credit to @StephanDowless